# Which changes count as "content changes" in Mobile Safari that prevent mousedown, mouseup, and click events?

Tags: mouseevent, mobile-safari

[As documented in the Safari Web Content Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW7), certain changes made to the document in a `mouseover` or `mousemove` handler will prevent `mousedown`, `mouseup`, and `click` events from firing on the element:

[image: Figure 6-4. One-finger gesture emulating a mouse]

Is there a complete list of changes to the document that count as "content changes"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a complete list, but here are some changes that count as content changes, and others that do not count as content changes:

### Content changes

- Call [appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild)
  http://fiddle.jshell.net/EDB3b/show/
- Reveal an element hidden by `display:none`
  http://fiddle.jshell.net/EDB3b/3/show/
- Reveal an element hidden by `visibility:hidden`
  http://fiddle.jshell.net/EDB3b/4/show/

### Non-content changes

- Set [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.innerHTML)
  http://fiddle.jshell.net/EDB3b/1/show/
- Call [insertAdjacentHTML()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.insertAdjacentHTML)
  http://fiddle.jshell.net/EDB3b/2/show/
- Set [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.outerHTML)
  http://fiddle.jshell.net/EDB3b/5/show/
- Change the text color
  http://fiddle.jshell.net/EDB3b/6/show/
- Add a class
  http://fiddle.jshell.net/EDB3b/7/show/
- Hide an element via `display:none`
  http://fiddle.jshell.net/EDB3b/8/show/
- Hide an element via `visibility:hidden`
  http://fiddle.jshell.net/EDB3b/9/show/
- Call [removeChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/node.removeChild)
  http://fiddle.jshell.net/EDB3b/10/show/

### See also

- [How Mobile Safari emulates mouse events](http://sitr.us/2011/07/28/how-mobile-safari-emulates-mouse-events.html)
- [The iOS event cascade and innerHTML](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2014/02/the_ios_event_c.html)